# Getting stdout contents without disabling cout/cin

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, console-application

Is it possible to save terminal (previously) written contents (stdout), to an array of strings:

```
vector<string> lines;
```

without disabling `cin/cout` normal functionality, in a linux console application.

In a terminal window in addition to characters there's coloring information for each character.  Is there a way to save them in another array?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to write inside a program to `std::cout` and have the data appear both on the terminal and in some program-internal data structure, you would use a custom stream buffer. Here us a simple example of how this would look:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>

struct capturebuf
    : std::streambuf
{
    std::ostream&   d_out;
    std::streambuf* d_sbuf;
    std::string&       d_str;
public:
    capturebuf(std::ostream& out, std::string& str)
        : d_out(out)
        , d_sbuf(out.rdbuf())
        , d_str(str)
    {
        out.rdbuf(this);
    }
    ~capturebuf() {
        this->d_out.rdbuf(this->d_sbuf);
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            this->d_str.push_back(c);
        }
        return this->d_sbuf->sputc(c);
    }
    int sync() { return this->d_sbuf->pubsync(); }
};
```

The above stream buffer will just add each character written to the string referenced during construction. The characters are also forwarded to the passed stream buffer. The forwarding to `pubsync()` is needed to make sure the underlying stream is flushed at the appropriate times.

To actually use it, you need to install it into `std::cout`. Since the constructor and destructor of `capturebuf` already do the registration/deregistration, all it takes is to construct a corresponding object:

```
int main()
{
    std::string capture;
    {
        capturebuf buf(std::cout, capture);
        std::cout << "hello, world\n";
    }
    std::cout << "caught '" << capture << "'\n";
}
```

This code doesn't quite do what you asked but nearly: you'd just need to process newlines differently. What is entirely missing is buffering which isn't needed to get the functionality but to get the performance. The above was typed in on a mobile device and is provably riddled with typos but the approach should work as is.

Comment: +1. your code does not disable `cout`. btw, it cannot record what happen before. all previously written data. And also coloring info.. ...std::char_traits is a template. } forgotten.. I edited but rejected,

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: How do you expect a program to recover the data previously written? Ask yourself how that could possibly work? The best that you can do is use a terminal that records everything written into it. Programs like 'screen' or 'script'. Or set gnome-terminal to 'unlimited' scrollback and do Select All, Copy, then paste into a text editor and save.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I expect so because they are in terminal buffer. And it's completely possible in Windows Console.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I was translating a backgammon Windows Console Program for linux. I did not want to resort to ncurses or so. I succeeded: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a51ka.jpg.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: The Windows Console is very much a different thing than a Unix console. The Windows Console tries to simulate a DOS screen with direct memory access. The Unix console/tty simulates a character-at-a-time teletype connected by a slow serial cable.