# Read from past console entries

Tags: c++, input, output, console-application

Let's say my program or another program did:

```
cout << "Hi" << endl;
```

And I want to read the last line entered into the console.

Something like:

```
string s=lastline();
```

s should have "Hi" as its contents.

Or to take it one step further, get the entire contents of the console put into something (vector, array, string, string stream, etc).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you mean like piping output from one program into another?

Comment: Sort of, yes. But I want it to include user input, not just program-program. And be program dependant. I know *nix has it built in with | symbol, but It's not really what I'm looking for

Comment: What OS ? Are looking for something portable ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631518/getting-stdout-contents-without-disabling-cout-cin)

Comment: @Josh: That vector is only visible to that single program. This should be able to be accesed from any program run from the terminal.

Comment: @quantdev: Portable would be best, but also different ways to do it on windows/*nix would be fine